# Appengine JPA update

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa-2.0, datanucleus

Hi I am using Google App Engine SDK 1.7.3 and JPA for Datanucleus.
I can't update an object that is in the variable `t`.

I have written my code as indicated in the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403515/appengine-datastore-object-with-id-is-managed-by-a-different-object-manage).

If I use the code:

```
    PersistenceManager persistenceManager=JDOHelper.getPersistenceManager(t);
    persistenceManager.refresh(t);
    return t;
```

I get:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method not supported with JPA
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAPersistenceManager.refresh(JPAPersistenceManager.java:693)
    at com.appspot.diasporajava.dao.GenericDaoImpl.update(GenericDaoImpl.java:74)
```

If I use the code:

```
return this.emf.createEntityManager().merge(t);
```

Where emf is an EntityManagerFactory.

I get:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Object with id "com.appspot.diasporajava.entities.Post@447cc9c9" is managed by a different Object Manager
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:302)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.merge(JPAEntityManager.java:576)
    at com.appspot.diasporajava.dao.GenericDaoImpl.update(GenericDaoImpl.java:76)
```

Do I have to keep open my persistence manager all the time?

[A related ticket](http://www.jpox.org/servlet/jira/browse/NUCCORE-284).

The ocde I use to create objects is the following:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public T create(final T t) {    
    EntityManager em = this.emf.createEntityManager();
    em.persist(t);
    em.close();
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that I did not close the `EntityManager` when I got the object `t` the first time.